# Is there a way of using orderby in a forloop C#?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, sql-order-by

I have a for loop where i want to orderby the name alphabetically

```
a
b
c
d
```

looking how to do this, wondered even if i could use linq orderby inside the forloop?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: A loop of that? A loop of strings? You want to Order this strings by name? If so, just do yourList.OrderBy(); If not, give us more information. Code is welcome too.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Item> myItems = new List<Item>();
//load myitems
foreach(Item i in myItems.OrderBy(t=>t.name))
{
 //Whatever
}
```

Comment: a slightly noobish question, will the orderby execute on each iteration of the loop thereby causing a performance hit?

Comment: No, just the one time

Comment: For everyone who wonders why this doesn't work: Check if you have included the `using System.Linq;` line.

Answer (score 2):

```
new string[] { "d", "c", "b", "a" }
    .OrderBy(s => s)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(s => MessageBox.Show(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Loop at all.  Just use LINQ:

```
List<MyClass> aList = new List<MyClass>();

// add data to aList

aList.OrderBy(x=>x.MyStringProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` needs an `IEnumerable<T>`  LINQ order-by takes in one `IEnumerable<T>` and gives you a sorted `IEnumerable<T>`.  So yes, it should work.